SSH client hangs for long right after start
I have a problem that my machine has an SSH client that very slowly establishes connection. It is hanging right after starting the command.  When I run it with triple debug flag (-vvv), it even then pauses for a minute or two before anything happens. All I see is:
OpenSSH_9.7p1 Ubuntu-7ubuntu4, OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024

After a long time it proceeds normally. What might be the issue? I was trying to connect to
same machines in my corporate network from another clients and only this particular machine (it's client) has problem.
I have additionally found, that another user, e.g. root does not have this long hang. Are there any local settings for ssh client that might affect that?
I was also trying some solutions from the internet, mostly adding some flags to the host I want to connect.  I put for example:
Host XXX
    HostName X.X.X.X
    User XXX
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/xxxx
    GSSAPIAuthentication no
    ObscureKeystrokeTiming no

More info:

Ubuntu 24.04 desktop, xfce
OpenSSH_9.7p1, OpenSSL 3.3.1 4


Okay after raising ticket for corporate networking support it  turned out that there was NIS (network information service) that was performing additional verifications.  They were invisible for ssh client event with very  descriptive debug. So the solution in this case is basically to contact the support :D
